# What does `pcie_aspm` do?

Tags: linux

Where is this kernel flag (pcie_aspm) documented? I'm sure it does something, and [I just turned it off to get wired Ethernet driver (e1000e) working](https://serverfault.com/q/193114/18822).

Answer (score 14):

So, the first hit on Google for "pcie_aspm" is:

[[patch] pci: document the pcie_aspm kernel parameter](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2008-09/msg08476.html)

and that documentation is in the current kernel `Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt`, where it says:

```
    pcie_aspm=      [PCIE] Forcibly enable or disable PCIe Active State Power
                    Management.
            off     Disable ASPM.
            force   Enable ASPM even on devices that claim not to support it.
                    WARNING: Forcing ASPM on may cause system lockups.
```

And in turn, google for "pcie active state power management" leads to  [PCI Express* Architecture Power Management](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/pci-express/pci-express-architecture-power-management-rev-1-1-paper.html) document, which explans that ASPM does pretty much what the name implies.

Comment: What's the difference between ASPM and ACPI, is this just ACPI for PCIE?

Comment: Is there anyway to turn ASPM for just my Ethernet device? What does ACPI do for PCIe without ASPM.. I'm just wanting to know the practical implications of ASPM, my wired ethernet device is supposed to support different power states.. that sounds awkward.. Is that even possible?

Comment: Welcome to the future, where the first hit on Google is a post ranting about the first hit on Google.

Comment: Related Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management