# Setting pcie_aspm=off at runtime

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, xen, pci-express

I'm running Centos 6.8 with 3.18.41-20.el6.x86_64 Xen kernel. Due to [this problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/193114/linux-e1000e-intel-networking-driver-problems-galore-where-do-i-start) (e1000e Detected Hardware Unit Hang) I updated my grub.conf appending arg `pcie_aspm=off` to the default kernel, but I can't reboot this hypervisor at the moment. I would like to set the variable at runtime if possible.

This is my current status:

```
# cat /sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy
[default] performance powersave
```

Is it possible to `echo off > /sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy` in order to achieve the same result? I think it doesn't make sense because **off** basically disables the function. What's the best option then? Would **performance** be a good workaround for my case? (see [Centos6 ASPM guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/ASPM.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put changes in grub and rebuilt grub to take effect, after reboot it will show you to :-

cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/rhel-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=rhel/root rd.lvm.lv=rhel/swap rhgb    pcie_aspm=off quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: You could also edit boot parameters when booting.